# Need help navigating lists when converting JSON into dataframe/CSV

Tags: r, json, dataframe, csv, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a javascript rendered table and after trying both selenium and phantomJS I've decided that JSON would be the easiest way to do it. However I am quite new to R and not very good at handling lists, and because of that I cannot get my data into the table format I desire. I've looked at a number of solutions but for some reason they don't really work on the JSON I have.

The JSON data is rendered through [this URL](https://aemo.com.au/aemo/api/v1/GasBBReporting/DailyProductionAndFlow?FacilityIds=540093,580010,540101,544261,540047,530030,540083,540096,580020,540071,540077,520075,540059,520054,520090,540094,540098,540080,540090,540086,540050,540097,540055,520047,540089,540070,540092,530071,530042,540088,540075,544253,540061,530038,530039,530040,580100,580040,540064,530043,550050,550045,550046,550054,520053,530061,520060,580050,540084,530041,530044,580060,580070,540065,550052,530060,540058,540085,540102,540073,540057,540095,544260,540110,540040,540082,540072,540062,540103,550061,550060,540060,540066,540067,540076,540068,580210,570050,540051,532005,530110,540045,540046,540091,580030,540069,540087,580180,540074&FromGasDate=07/08/2020&ToGasDate=07/09/2020). And [this](https://aemo.com.au/en/energy-systems/gas/gas-bulletin-board-gbb/data-portal) is the actual website where the table is located.

What I've done so far is to try to parse the JSON into R and coerce it into a dataframe, based on what I've seen from most answers on stackoverflow.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
rf <- GET(url) #the entire URL is very long so I'm not putting it here
rfc <- content(rf)
```

Doing this returns me a large list of four elements, rfc. I then apply the following function.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)     
json_file <- lapply(rfc, function(x) {
      x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
      unlist(x)
    })
```

This returns me an error:

```
Error in x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Given that I only need the second element of the list, which is where the information is at, I attempt to subset it:

```
  json_file <- lapply(rfc[2], function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  unlist(x)
})
```

This returns me a large list, 12mb in size. When I try to coerce it to a dataframe using as.data.frame, R returns me 506472 observations of 1 variable. The different columns have all been squashed into one and the headers are gone.

Can anyone tell me how I should go about doing this? There's a free online JSON to CSV [converter here](https://konklone.io/json/) that does exactly what I need beautifully. This is what it produces:

[image]

Unfortunately this is not a solution. Because I intend to run this in Shiny I want to do everything within R. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the element `rfc$data$DailyProductionAndFlowList`, which itself is effectively a list of single-row data frames, and bind them together. You'll need to overwrite the `NULL` values first:

```r
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(rfc$data$DailyProductionAndFlowList, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- "NULL"
  as.data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}))
```

To show you that the result is sensible, I've put it in a `tibble` here for nicer printing:

```
as_tibble(df)
#> # A tibble: 3,997 x 11
#>    GasDate FacilityId FacilityName LocationId LocationName Demand Supply
#>    <chr>        <int> <chr>             <int> <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 2020-0~     520047 Eastern Gas~     520008 Sydney        94.4     0  
#>  2 2020-0~     520047 Eastern Gas~     520009 Canberra      16.5     0  
#>  3 2020-0~     520047 Eastern Gas~     530015 Longford Hub   0     234. 
#>  4 2020-0~     520047 Eastern Gas~     590011 Regional - ~  22.4     0  
#>  5 2020-0~     520047 Eastern Gas~     590012 Regional - ~   2.68   19.4
#>  6 2020-0~     520047 Eastern Gas~     520008 Sydney       113.      0  
#>  7 2020-0~     520047 Eastern Gas~     520009 Canberra      19.7     0  
#>  8 2020-0~     520047 Eastern Gas~     530015 Longford Hub   0     225. 
#>  9 2020-0~     520047 Eastern Gas~     590011 Regional - ~  27.5     0  
#> 10 2020-0~     520047 Eastern Gas~     590012 Regional - ~   5.05   20.1
#> # ... with 3,987 more rows, and 4 more variables: TransferIn <dbl>,
#> #   TransferOut <dbl>, HeldInStorage <chr>, LastUpdated <chr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
library( data.table )
library( rjson )

#location of  data
json.url = "https://aemo.com.au/aemo/api/v1/GasBBReporting/DailyProductionAndFlow?FacilityIds=540093,580010,540101,544261,540047,530030,540083,540096,580020,540071,540077,520075,540059,520054,520090,540094,540098,540080,540090,540086,540050,540097,540055,520047,540089,540070,540092,530071,530042,540088,540075,544253,540061,530038,530039,530040,580100,580040,540064,530043,550050,550045,550046,550054,520053,530061,520060,580050,540084,530041,530044,580060,580070,540065,550052,530060,540058,540085,540102,540073,540057,540095,544260,540110,540040,540082,540072,540062,540103,550061,550060,540060,540066,540067,540076,540068,580210,570050,540051,532005,530110,540045,540046,540091,580030,540069,540087,580180,540074&FromGasDate=07/08/2020&ToGasDate=07/09/2020"
#retrieve lastest data
mydata <- data.table::rbindlist( rjson::fromJSON( file = json.url )$data$DailyProductionAndFlowList, 
                                 use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE )
```